# Adjoining Root over Z/2

Tags: field-theory

Let α be a root of the polynomial $f(x) = x^2 + x + 1$.

(a) Construct the field F of 4 elements by adjoining a root α over Z/2. (Write down all elements of F).

(b) Find the inverse of α+1 in F.

I was a little confused by the question as I was not sure if I had to find the actual complex number equal to root α, or if I could just keep using α. I assumed the latter and this was my approach for a):

As Z/2 = {0,1}, then adjoining α to Z/2 to form a field F gives F = ${0, 1, α, α + 1}$.

Then, for b):

Consider $α(α+1) = α^2 + α$. As we know $α^2 + α + 1 = 0$, then $α^2 + α = -1$, congruent to 1 (mod 2). Thus, inverse is α.

Is this approach correct?

Comment: There is no "actual complex number equal to root $\alpha$", because your field is not contained in the complex numbers.

Comment: I see, so is my answer correct as is?

Comment: I don't know how much detail your grader will ask for, but what you have is correct.